# embed query inside div tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This is not the full html page! The playlist works perfectly all by itself and it works inside my html file, but I dont no how to embed it inside a div tag called contentStory.
Can anyone help me? I'm sure it's simple. Is it the path? Should $('body') be an absolute path to the div tag? To you tech developers, sorry for such a goofy question.

```
<head>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.6.1.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="../plugin/jquery-jplayer/jquery.jplayer.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="../plugin/ttw-music-player-min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/myplaylist.js"></script>

 <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var description = 'This is ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce id tortor nisi. Aenean sodales diam ac lacus elementum scelerisque. Suspendisse a dui vitae lacus faucibus venenatis vel id nisl. Proin orci ante, ultricies nec interdum at, iaculis venenatis nulla. ';

        $('body').ttwMusicPlayer(myPlaylist, {
            autoPlay:false, 
            description:description,
            jPlayer:{
                swfPath:'music-player/plugin/jquery-jplayer' //You need to override the default swf path any time the directory structure changes
            }
        });
    });
  </script>
  </head>
  <body class="wireframe">
  <div id="page">
  <header>.....</header>
  <div>….</div>
  <div>….</div>
  <div>….</div>
  <div>….</div>
  <div>….</div>
  <div id="contentStory"></div>
  <footer>….</footer>

  </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: What are actually trying to accomplish? Describe your desired end result.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `contentStory` ID to locate it

```
$('#contentStory').ttwMusicPlayer(myPlaylist, {
       autoPlay:false, 
       description:description,
       jPlayer:{
            swfPath:'music-player/plugin/jquery-jplayer' //You need to override the default swf path any time the directory structure changes
       }
});
```

Comment: I want this audio playlist to appear inside a html page on a website.

Comment: I want this audio playlist to appear inside a html page on a website. I tried $('contentStory') but when I do that, the entire playlist disappears all together. http://www.morethanconquerorschurch.org/music-player/demo/index2.html

Comment: @Sheree Smith I'm not going to visit your site but if you recreate your scenario in http://jsfiddle.net/ I'll take a look there.